# $L_+$, $L_-$ Old terminology and Quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Two Quantum mechanics Questions one simple one, and one stupid one:

For angular momentum:

Considering the appropriate

```
    i) Mathematical motivation
```

How do we derive $L_+$ and $L_-$
I think I am looking for an explanation that would mention something about roots and weights. 
May be mention something about restricted simultaneous diagonalization.

```
   ii) Physical motivation
```

Defining some nice properties with associated upper and lower bounds.

Just to mention I just want to  know where $L_+ $ and $L_-$ come from. I know its almost trivial but I'm looking to see something. . . I know its not defined, its derived in two ways.

For some general stuff about the importance of preserving the old language.

In Weinberg's text on QM(It's ok to claim I don't understand it), the questions in chapter 2 seem to employ a lot of old, and largely still used terminology. Question 2p and 1s type language, and Question 6 has something along the lines of "Lyman $\alpha$" transitions, which is fairly understood language among experts. I have heard these things before when taking QM, but I just feel so put off by it that I have to keep reminding myself what these things mean when I see them. 
   I know "par excellence" Weinberg is correct to promote such language, but his reputation aside, is this the best possible language* to describe these things? I recall feeling very stupid until I reminded myself of what this meant.
   I want to know if this sort of language* is used by modern researchers working in AMO, or if perhaps the language has evolved.
   Should I just stop complaining and memorize these balmer, Lyman  . . . .  and other historically relevant words, that are still everywhere including Record exams and other places I don't want to find myself in.
   The reason this bothers me is I don't want memorize values of l m n  ; s p d f and other such things for specific cases and make associations along these lines. Is there some modern  cure to this problem
   I know its a really stupid question.

In the event the question is too childish just leave some references

Comment: Balmer and Lyman lines are spectral lines that you see when you electrify hydrogen and disperse the light that comes out using a monochromator. They're related to energy levels of the hydrogen atom (which is emitting the light).

Comment: Personally I don't actually take the time to memorize what specific energy levels the Balmer, Lyman etc. lines correspond to in the hydrogen wavefunctions, I just mentally associate the words "Balmer, Lyman,..." with "glowing hydrogen", and if I really need the exact specifics I just ask Google for more information.

Comment: nice, the "glowing" captures the essence of the concept.

Comment: As for the angular momentum raising ($L_+$) and lowering ($L_-$) operators, as mentioned on [this site](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node209.html), it's somewhat straightforward to show that they act as raising and lowering operators in the sense that $L_\pm Y_{l,m}=\hbar\sqrt{l(l+1)-m(m\pm1)}Y_{l,m\pm1}$, similar to the behavior of the raising and lowering operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$ on the Gauss-Hermite functions. This probably isn't the explanation you're looking for, but just food for thought.

Comment: Nice.  I will be supplementing study with the notes on the page.